# Why doesn't ${#$2} work?

Tags: bash, sh

I have this line in a small bash function:

```
if [ ${#$2} -lt 25 ]; then
```

But it gives me `Bad substitution` on the `${#$2}`. What am I doing wrong there? I'm trying to get the length in characters of the second command line argument. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter name is `2`, not `$2`.

```
if [ ${#2} -lt 25 ]; then
```

Comment: You're right, that works, but I don't understand why. Thought command line arguments were referenced by `$1`, `$2`, and so on.

Comment: Correct, but just like the variable `x` is referenced by `$x`, so is the special parameter `2` referenced by `$2`. With `${#2}`, you already have the dollar sign; you're just adding the `#` operator to the expansion.